# xdotool: what are "class" and "classname" for a window?

Tags: xorg, xdotool

In light of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254854/674 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458895/how-can-i-bring-a-background-gui-job-to-the-front-of-my-desktop, there is an example from manpage of xdotool

```
# Activate google-chrome when you move the mouse to the bottom-left corner: 
xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom-left search --class google-chrome windowactivate
```

The manpage says

> --class Match against the window class.
>
> --classname Match against the window classname.

What are "class" and "classname"?

What possible values do they have?

How can I find out the class and classname of a window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Under X11 windows have  [XWindowdAttributes structure](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowAttributes.html) and [XClassHint structures](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/wm-class.html#XClassHint)  properties from which applications get information about windows. Specifically the last one is responsible for the `WM_CLASS` property, two comma-separated strings, which can be seen easily via `xprop` command. For instance, Chrome has

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "google-chrome", "Google-chrome"
```

These two are [documented](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_CLASS) as:

> - A string that names the particular instance of the application to which the client that owns this window belongs. ...
> - A string that names the general class of applications to which the client that owns this window belongs. Resources that are specified by
>     class apply to all applications that have the same class name....

Thus, for example Hangouts extension for Chrome, has same class name, but different instance name:

```
$ xprop | grep 'CLASS'
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "crx_nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd", "Google-chrome"
```

This allows tools such as `xdotool` search all windows of particular application type, or specific window instance. For instance, this also can be useful property for something like docks that group windows under the same icon of an application.

In particular for `xdotool`, `classname` corresponds with the first string, and `class` corresponds the second string. In my example with Chrome and Hangouts apps:

```
$ xdotool search -classname crx_nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd
96469129

$ xdotool search -class Google-chrome
96469069
109051905
109051907
96468993
96469129
109051912
109051924
```

---

This also can be apparent from looking at the source code. Let's focus on classname for example. In the [cmd_search.c](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/cmd_search.c) we have a search struct built up, which has a search mask property(lines 171 to 173).

This gets passed to `xdo_search_windows` function defined in [xdo_search.c](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/5c0f650d331c8dcfcaea832a11c937c4f571580f/xdo_search.c#L31) , which in turn calls [`check_window_match`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/5c0f650d331c8dcfcaea832a11c937c4f571580f/xdo_search.c#L203), that in turn goes to  [_xdo_match_window_classname](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/5c0f650d331c8dcfcaea832a11c937c4f571580f/xdo_search.c#L286), which finally ends up [retrieving both structures](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/5c0f650d331c8dcfcaea832a11c937c4f571580f/xdo_search.c#L146) mentioned in the beginning of this answer with the standard [Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) functions [XGetWindowAttributes](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowAttributes.html) and [XGetClassHint](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XGetClassHint.html).

---

Side note: Gtk apps apparently [always create a small parent window with a child window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3909713/3701431), which means you may get confusing results when searching for a specific window.

Comment: Thanks. Are "class name" and "instance name" given by `xprop` correponding to "class", "classname" or "name" in `xdotool search`?

Comment: @Tim Yes, they are. I've updated my answer slightly. See the update.

Comment: @Michael It may to do with Ubuntu using Wayland instead of X11 in more recent versions. Ideally, it should wait for you to select a window with the mouse - then the output appears. If you do that, but there's still no output - likely because your system uses Wayland