# Using Xdotool to type in a Libreoffice Document

Tags: bash, scripts, libreoffice, xdotool

I have often wondered how to automate libreoffice by using xdotool. I know that the window has to be selected out of the window stack, and I tried programming it as a window bash variable under xdotool in the bash script. I then tried sending the next keypress to the window but to no result. Right now I want to pass the ctrl+N command to the libre office window to open a new document.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/libreoffice
mywindow=$(xdotool search --class libreoffice)
xdotool windowactivate $mywindow && xdotool key --window $mywindow Next
xdotool key ctrl+n
```

I do get an error code

```
There are no windows in the stack.
Invalid window '%1'
Usage: windowactivate [options] [window=%1]
--sync - only exit once window is active (is visible + active)
If no window is given, %1 is used. See WINDOW STACK in xdotool(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To more selectively find a LibreOffice Writer window (and e.g. not a Calc window), use this: `mywindow=$(xdotool search --class libreoffice-writer)`. You can see the class of open windows with the command `wmctrl -lx`. This lists the more [generic classname and the more specific class](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060170/xdotool-what-are-class-and-classname-for-a-window), separated by a dot. For libreoffice, it is `libreoffice.libreoffice-writer`.
- Beware: the `xdotool search` command will retrieve all windows of a certain class. Thus, with multiple windows, the variable will contain multiple identifiers separated by a space, e.g. `66167017 65540686`. `windowactivate`, however, only supports a single argument.
- After executing the `libreoffice` command, the process will fork to the background. No window is created yet. That is why `winactivate` fails. Use the `--sync` option to have the `winactivate` command wait for the window to be effectively created: `mywindow=$(xdotool search --sync --class libreoffice.writer)`

Comment: It works! Thanks. Could I also use windowfocus? It's on the same virtual desktop, so would windowactivate be necessary?

Comment: `man xdotool` recommends to prefer `windowactivate` although `windowfocus` may also work in your case. These two involve different methods.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be putting LO in background, then add delay between the `xdotool` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/libreoffice &
sleep 10
mywindow=$(xdotool search --class libreoffice)
xdotool windowactivate $mywindow && xdotool key --window $mywindow Next
xdotool key ctrl+n
```